# Como consultar o último dos elementos filhos e retornar seu elemento pai usando o Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho vários elementos DIV "item" dentro de um elemento Pai DIV "elemento-pai".
Preciso fazer uma busca pelo último elemento "item" e retornar o elemento pai "elemento-pai" no qual ele pertence.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="elemento-pai">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>

$('#id').find('.item').last().closest('.container');
```

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe um método chamado parent().

```
$("#id").find('.item').last().parent()
```

Comment: Obrigado @tomasantunes! Funcionou!!